# Unable to lookup idp connection metadata for entityid='http://sp.example.com/sp'

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

I have service provider application `http://sp.example.com/sp` and when user accesses it through a browser, user is redirected from my SP application to IdP server which is configured on PingFederate server with an SP connection(http://sp.example.com/sp) as entity id. User is redirected through SAML protocol with `SAML AuthnRequest` to IdP.  But on Ping server I keep getting this error which says

```
unable to lookup idp connection metadata for entityid='http://sp.example.com/sp'
```

Does anyone have face similar error before with Ping? This is SP-initiated SSO.

Request I am sending to PingFederate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sp.example.com/sp" Destination="https://idp.com/sp/ACS.saml2" ForceAuthn="false" ID="_93313f7882ff7b3274da46502c4cf072" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2014-04-29T15:15:04.666Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Version="2.0"><samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sp.example.com/sp</samlp:Issuer><saml2p:NameIDPolicy xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AllowCreate="true" SPNameQualifier="https://sp.example.com/sp"/><saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Comparison="exact"><saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Comment: Can you post your metadata somewhere, https://gist.github.com/ maybe?

Comment: @Stefan Here you go https://gist.github.com/yogsma/11404390

Comment: I have not worked with PIng but it soundlike something is wrong with your idp-metadata. could you import it correctly to Ping?

Comment: Yes and I sent the metadata and all details to Ping Support, they didn't find anything wrong. They are not able to resolve the issue yet.

Comment: As your support engineer indicated in your case you have with us, the destination that you have defined in your SP configuration is wrong. Instead of pointing it to https://idp.com/sp/ACS.saml2, it needs to point to https://idp.com/idp/SSO.saml2.

The engineer you have working with you is very good, and she knows what she's talking about. I would bet that the conference call that she has scheduled for you will clear it all up.

Comment: @AndyK.-PingIdentity Thanks Andy. It resolved the issue last evening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find possible solutions to your problem in Ping's support center:

https://www.pingidentity.com/support/solutions/index.cfm/SSO-fails-with-Unable-to-lookup-sp-or-idp-connection-metadata-for-entityid

> In the server.log, the error "Unable to lookup sp connection metadata
>   for entityid" is seen. This is usually an indication that there is a
>   mismatch between the Partner Entity ID (Connection ID) configured in
>   the IDP-side PingFederate SP Connection and the actual entity ID of
>   the partner, and therefore PF cannot determine which SP Connection to
>   use when a SAML AuthnRequest comes in from the SP in the SP-initiated
>   SSO use case.

https://www.pingidentity.com/support/solutions/index.cfm/Unable-to-lookup-sp-connection-metadata-for-entityid

> Since Entity ID is case sensitive, if there is a mismatch between the
>   value entered for the Partner's Entity ID (Connection ID) field in the
>   PingFederate Administrative Console and what the partner is sending in
>   the SAML protocol message, then the SSO attempt will fail with the
>   "Unable to lookup sp (or idp) connection" error message.
>
> The solution is to verify the Partner's Entity ID (Connection ID)
>   setting matches exactly what is sent by the partner in the SAML
>   messages.

Comment: I have checked those solutions from Ping, but those have not helped to resolve the issue. Only thing I am finding fishy is that the error says "unable to lookup idp connection meta data for entity id='http://sp.example.com/sp'" and that entity id I have used in SP connection in Ping as an entity ID. I am not sure if I have done correct configuration in Ping

Comment: So your SP is *not* using PingFederate if I understand your setup correctly? Can you show us what the AuthnRequest looks like you are generating and sending to the IDP (PF)?

Comment: @Ian I posted AuthnRequest.